# jQuery.parseJSON - Chrome and Safari automatically parsing JSON

Tags: jquery, json

The following function results in the response variable being null in Chrome and Safari but not Firefox.

```
function updatePage(response){ // This argument differs by browser

    response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

    for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
        // conduct magic
    };

};
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

This is because feeding jQuery.parseJSON() anything but a JSON **string** returns null. It seems Chrome and Safari automatically parse JSON without explicitly being requested. If I test the "response" argument before trying to parse it with jQuery, it's already a JSON object in both Chrome and Safari. However, in Firefox it's still a string.

The only solution I've come up with to handle this across browsers is to determine if "response" has already been parsed by checking its constructor:

```
function updatePage(response){

    if(response.constructor === String){
        response = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
    };

    for(var i=0; i<response.length; i++){
        // conduct magic
    };

};
```

Am I missing something or is this the only way to handle this currently? Seems like jQuery.parseJSON would detect the user-agent and just return the argument as-is in the case of Chrome/Safari.

**Pertinent information**

- This is jQuery 1.6.1
- The response Content-Type from the server is application/json
- The response argument is originating from your standard jQuery AJAX call:

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: API_URL + queryString + '&limit=' + limit,
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    context: document.body,
    success: updatePage,
    error: function(err){
        console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not Chrome or Safari, it's jQuery that does the parsing if it sees the appropriate `Content-Type` on the response. (Update: And the `Content-Type` you've added to the question is correct.) I can't immediately see why it wouldn't be doing it on Firefox.

You can force it to always do the parsing by adding `dataType: 'json'` to your call, details in [the `jQuery.ajax` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Then you wouldn't call `parseJSON` at all, `response` would already be the deserialized object.

Comment: Well, the Content-Type is in fact "application/json." Why isn't this happening in Firefox?

Comment: I think we're playing edit tag. You're right, adding the dataType: 'json' eliminates the issue. I'm still vexed as to why the issue doesn't pop up in Firefox.

Comment: @j33r: Yeah, that's very strange. With that content type, it should be automatically parsed by jQuery on Firefox as well, and it *is* in my tests with both Firefox 3.6 and 4.0. I'd take a close look at the response, not because you can't work around it with `dataType`, but because they may be something wrong in there.

Comment: I'm running Firefox 4.0.1 on OSX 10.6.7. The response header is: Server nginx
Date Tue, 21 Jun 2011 07:50:31 GMT
Content-Type application/json
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Connection keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... *
Content-Encoding gzip So yeah, no idea. Thanks though.

Comment: I've just got the 100% same problem with my Firefox 13.0 on Linux Mint (coincidentally on the same Jun 21). I was searching for it and found your question. Thanks @ChrisCummings for the question and T.J. Crowder for the answer.