# Chrome-only error with jquery ajax: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to return results from the youtube api. My code is as follows:

```
function Vget(strt){

$.get("https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos", { q: "soccer, 'start-index':strt,     'max-results':"5", v:"2",alt:"jsonc" },
 function(dta){
 var dt= $.parseJSON(dta);
var res= dt.data.items;
var tr=  dt.data.totalItems;

if ( (dt.data) && tr>0){
  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
 //do something with results
  }


}
})
}
```

But the line "var res= dt.data.items;" is giving me an error in Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of null".

Firebug doesnt show any errors...

**EDIT:**

I tried commenting out the "var dt= $.parseJSON(dta);" and replacing the "dt.data" with "dta.data. and using the dta object straight. Which works great on Chrome, but then Firefox gives an error: "dta.data in undefined"!

**EDIT 2** : here's what the returned json looks like:

```
{"apiVersion":"2.1","data":{"updated":"2012-09-20T16:45:14.080Z","totalItems":153820,"startIndex":1,"itemsPerPage":2,"items":[{"id":"PO2b3cggqs0","uploaded":"2009-05-04T05:50:37.000Z","updated":"2012-09-20T03:28:49.000Z","uploader":"jbtdotcom","category":"Music","title":"Zebra - Official Video","description":"Official video clip for the JBT song, 'Zebra' from the album 'Sunrise Over Sea'. www.johnbutlertrio.com","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PO2b3cggqs0/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/PO2b3cggqs0/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PO2b3cggqs0&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=PO2b3cggqs0"},"content":{"5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/PO2b3cggqs0?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v8.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnNqiDI3ZvtPBMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v3.cache1.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQnNqiDI3ZvtPBMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":240,"rating":4.9585986,"likeCount":"4351","ratingCount":4396,"viewCount":1114536,"favoriteCount":5266,"commentCount":638,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"moderated","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}},{"id":"fljKx9nvrL4","uploaded":"2012-01-19T14:00:00.000Z","updated":"2012-09-20T06:03:17.000Z","uploader":"rhettandlink","category":"Entertainment","title":"Dope Zebra - Rhett & Link (Official Original Video) LMFAO","description":"This zebra is dope. Extended song on iTunes: dft.ba ** Official T-SHIRT: dft.ba Featured in LMFAO's Sorry For Party Rockin' music video and in their American Idol live performance on 4/19/12 and Billboard Music Awards on 5/20/12. You might have also spotted him on America's Got Talent...","thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/fljKx9nvrL4/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/fljKx9nvrL4/hqdefault.jpg"},"player":{"default":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fljKx9nvrL4&feature=youtube_gdata_player","mobile":"https://m.youtube.com/details?v=fljKx9nvrL4"},"content":{"5":"https://www.youtube.com/v/fljKx9nvrL4?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata","1":"rtsp://v1.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQm-rO_Zx8pYfhMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp","6":"rtsp://v1.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQm-rO_Zx8pYfhMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"},"duration":109,"aspectRatio":"widescreen","rating":4.958495,"likeCount":"55842","ratingCount":56427,"viewCount":4658199,"favoriteCount":32961,"commentCount":12834,"accessControl":{"comment":"allowed","commentVote":"allowed","videoRespond":"denied","rate":"allowed","embed":"allowed","list":"allowed","autoPlay":"allowed","syndicate":"allowed"}}]}}
```

Comment: It's a parseJson problem.
See [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420819/jquery-parsejson-chrome-and-safari-automatically-parsing-json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing the json to console and check the format of the data..

```
function(dta){
 console.log(dta); // Before Parsing
 var dt= $.parseJSON(dta);
 console.log(dt);  //After Parsing
```

Looks like you are not accessing the data properly

Comment: 'console.log(dta); // Before Parsing' returns the object with the expected videos, while "console.log(dt);  //After Parsing" returns "null"

Comment: See my edit in the question. It seems Chrome only recognizes the object without parsejson, while FF only recognizes it WITH parsejson???

Comment: I'm sorry sushanth reddy, I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: Hit F12 in your browser.. Send the request .. Then in the Network section of your developer too's you can see the request posted to the server. Click on the request which was sent.. In the response section you will have the json object

Comment: The result is too large for the comments, so I'm putting it in the question.

Comment: sure.. Just couple of entries should be fine