# Why can I access a JSON object in Chrome, but not in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, json, firefox, google-chrome

I have the following query string:

```
query = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20Precinct%20FROM%201Kj-5ett9nIpkr2-gkof0cUGiaZm1BDVZx9zv-iQ%20WHERE%20ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,%20RECTANGLE(LATLNG(40.7549937,%20-73.98841900000002),%20LATLNG(40.7549937,%20-73.98841900000002)))&key=AIzaSyBJ1SHkB7EWWVSyDiPUA1mWZDEKt7gISDk'
```

That returns the following object with an HTTP GET request:

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [
  "Precinct"
 ],
 "rows": [
  [
   "76"
  ]
 ]
}
```

So I'm trying to fetch that into a web browser using jQuery. This works OK in Firefox and Chrome:

```
$.get(precinctQuery, function(data){console.log(data)});
```

But Firefox doesn't like this:

```
$.get(precinctQuery, function(data){console.log(data.rows[0][0])});
```

Or this:

```
$.get(precinctQuery, function(data){console.log(data.['rows'][0][0])});
```

Both times, Firefox says the result is Undefined. Chrome returns the expected result, "76".

Is Chrome fixing this code behind the scenes so it works? Why doesn't Firefox like it?

Comment: You sure `data` is an array when you try and access its indeces? Or is still just a string containing a representation of an array?

Comment: I'd suggest that you check what exactly `data` is in Firefox.  It probably isn't what you expect so you need to see what it actually is.  If it were me, I'd set a breakpoint in your success callback and examine the data argument directly or use `console.log()` statements to examine `data`, `data.rows` and `data.rows[0]`.

Comment: You need to call `$.parseJSON` on the `data` received. Or you can just use `$.getJSON` from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. In Chrome `typeof data` returns `object`. In Firefox, `typeof data` returns `string`. It doesn't look like it's getting parsed.

Comment: Thanks, @nhahtdh! That's working great. I wonder why Chrome does the parsing automatically, but Firefox does not.

Comment: @MartinBurch: Related question (but it still a bit blur from the answer why there is a difference, though): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420819/jquery-parsejson-chrome-and-safari-automatically-parsing-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `json` upperhand on the `$.get` function, like this:

```
$.get(precinctQuery, function(data)
{
    console.log(data)
}, 'json');
```

This will determine the format of the data, `json` filter will parse the JSON for you, before returning it as `data`. `$.getJSON` will make the code shorter, but it is a shortcut for the above code.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to parse the JSON data to an readable object, the following code works just fine:

```
query = 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20Precinct%20FROM%201Kj-5ett9nIpkr2-gkof0cUGiaZm1BDVZx9zv-iQ%20WHERE%20ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,%20RECTANGLE(LATLNG(40.7549937,%20-73.98841900000002),%20LATLNG(40.7549937,%20-73.98841900000002)))&key=AIzaSyBJ1SHkB7EWWVSyDiPUA1mWZDEKt7gISDk';
$.get(query, function(data)
    {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(obj.rows[0][0]);
    }
);
```